# Creating a Summary from a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I've written python code that generates a two column dataframe containing a list of our staff, and the team they're assigned to that day (ie column A: staff member, column B: team). From this `dataframe`, I'd like to generate a `.txt` file or a string formatted as follows:

**Team 1** (line break)
*staff member* (line break)
*staff member* (line break)
*staff member* (line break)
**Team 2** (line break)
*staff member* (line break)

etc.

I have tried using `df.pivot()` to achieve something similar, but didn't have much luck. Apologies if this is a very basic question, I'm learning all of this as I go. Thank you!

[image: The format of my data]

Desired Output:
Winning Team
Dave
Alex
Sabrina
Losing Team
John
Douglas

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or a tabular format that shows you what you are looking for? If you are just creating a text file, you don't need to use pandas dataframes. You can just use a list or a dictionary and then use the built-in I/O Python functions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Hi @Shen and thanks for your response - I have added a screenshot of the format of my data, which is a CSV generated earlier in the process. The names in the data have been changed, but this is roughly what it looks like. I've chosen to use Pandas because the data is already in CSV format and it's being used throughout the project. I have also added the ideal output. The stage I'm struggling with is grouping all staff members under a single team heading in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Staff":["Julie", "Max", "Sam", "Paula", "Mary"],
               "Team": ["Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 2", "Team 1"]})
grouped = df.groupby("Team")
result_string = ""
for team, group in grouped:
    result_string += (team + "\n")
    for person in group["Staff"]:
        result_string += ("\t" + person + "\n")

print(f'Dataframe: \n{df}')
print('______________\nResult String:')
print(result_string)
```

PRINTS THE FOLLOWING:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @pakpe this does exactly what I'm after. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @j18273018 Please go ahead and accept my answer and vote it up if you like it. That’s how it works on this site.